# Send mail from Google Cloud Function using appspotmail.com

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send email to my organization users using appspotmail.com throw google cloud function.

is it possible?
has anyone any idea to do that?

according to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/) it is possible using appengine but there is no instruction doing that from Cloud Function

Answer (score 2):

The Mail API is exclusive for [App Engine Standard 1st generation runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/runtimes), so it is not available for any other environment.

You can use the alternatives in the documentation, like [Sendgrid](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid).

Comment: I use Gmail in Cloud Functions (Python) which works very well.

Comment: No, the SMTP interface.

Comment: @John I was basing myself on the docs, but your solution looks interesting. Feel free to write a full answer, as it might be better than using Sendgrid.

Comment: There are advantages to using a service such as sendgrid. I like your answer. If the questioner would like an example using the Python smtplib, Gmail and Cloud Functions, create a new question and I will post my code.